# PHP Проверка введенной даты

Tags: php

Есть поле ввода, в него пользователь вводит дату. Мне нужно чтобы дата пользователя была не меньше чем *(+2 дня от сегодня)* и не больше чем *(+ пол года от сегодня)*.

Ниже есть код проверки даты на **javascript**.

**Задание**: нужно сделать такую же проверку, только на **php**.
*(Отображение даты должно быть в формате 31.12.2016)*

```js
var tomorrow = new Date(); // получаем текущую дату №1
var pieceyear = new Date(); // получаем текущую дату №2

function dateFormat(date) {
  return ("0" + (date.getDate())).slice(-2) + '.' + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '.' + date.getFullYear();
}

function parseDate(dateStr) {
  var parts = dateStr.split('.');
  return new Date(+parts[2], -1 + (+parts[1]), +parts[0]);
}

tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2); // к дате №1 добавляем 2 дня
pieceyear.setMonth(pieceyear.getMonth() + 6); // к дате №2 добавляем 6 месяцев

$('#datepicker').val(dateFormat(tomorrow)); // значение поля становится на 2 дня больше сегодняшнего дня

function datevalidate() {
  var value = parseDate($('#datepicker').val());
  if (value < tomorrow) { // если дата меньше чем послезавтра
    $('#datepicker').val(dateFormat(tomorrow)); // присваиваем дату послезавтра
  } else if (value > pieceyear) { // если дата больше чем + пол года
    $('#datepicker').val(dateFormat(pieceyear)); // присваиваем дату на пол года больше
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="datepicker" onchange="datevalidate()">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$date = \Datetime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y', $input);
if (! $date) {
    // дата введена в неверном формате
}
//if ($date->format('d.m.Y') != $input) 
// datetime считает дату 31.11.2016 допустимым вариантом записи 01.12.2016

if ($date >= new \Datetime('+2 day') and $date < new \Datetime('+6 month')) {
    // дата валидна
} else {
    // дата вне требуемого диапазона
}
```

Вполне приятный нативный класс [`Datetime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)